# Selenium get element in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to get **number** in `small` tag in `HTML`

Html code:

```
...

<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label>Amount</label>
    <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="10" value="10">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Max Amount: 2000</small>
</div>

...
```

this code I have written returns `null`.
I want to get **2000** number in the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below solution

```
 WebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='form-group col-sm-12']/small"))
 String elementText=element.Text;

 Console.WriteLine("Text", Regex.Replace(elementText, "[^a-zA-Z]+", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need regex for this:

```
 WebElement ele= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//small[@class='form-class text-muted']"))
 String eleText = ele.Text;

 int eleVal = 0;
 int.tryParse(eleText, out eleVal);
```